# Amazon Mobile Ads not displaying Amazon Ads

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I have implemented Amazon Mobile Ads in accordance with this guide:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-ads/docs/quick-start

But I am having trouble getting ads displayed, and it looks as if my app is somehow rejected by Amazon ad server:

> 02-11 11:48:33.774: D/AmazonMobileAds AdLayout(10350): Ad size to be
>   determined automatically. 02-11 11:48:33.779: D/AbsListView(10350):
>   onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4 02-11 11:48:33.779:
>   D/AbsListView(10350): unregisterIRListener() is called  02-11
>   11:48:33.799: D/AbsListView(10350): onVisibilityChanged() is called,
>   visibility : 0 02-11 11:48:33.799: D/AbsListView(10350):
>   unregisterIRListener() is called  02-11 11:48:34.099:
>   D/AmazonMobileAds AdRequest WebRequest(10350): URL:
>   http://aax-us-east.amazon-adsystem.com/x/msdk?appId=&dinfo=%7B%22scalingFactor%22%3A%222.0%22%2C%22screenSize%22%3A%22720x1280%22%2C%22orientation%22%3A%22portrait%22%2C%22os%22%3A%22Android%22%2C%22model%22%3A%22GT-I9305%22%2C%22osVersion%22%3A%224.3%22%2C%22connectionType%22%3A%22Wifi%22%2C%22carrier%22%3A%22Chunghwa%20Telecom%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22make%22%3A%22samsung%22%2C%22country%22%3A%22US%22%7D&pkg=%7B%22v%22%3A%2215%22%2C%22lbl%22%3A%22Baby%20Monitor%22%2C%22vn%22%3A%220.5%22%2C%22pn%22%3A%22com.astrotek.babymonitor%22%7D&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Linux%3B%20U%3B%20Android%204.3%3B%20en-us%3B%20GT-I9305%20Build%2FJSS15J%29%20AppleWebKit%2F534.30%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Version%2F4.0%20Mobile%20Safari%2F534.30&ad-id=A6Ndy818A0Pko7-rm16G81E&isTest=true&adsdk=amznAdSDK-android-5.1.153&slot=portrait&sz=auto&mxsz=720x0&sha1_udid=262c355fe50b5d6934081c9bce568ac7fed963cb
>   02-11 11:48:34.629: I/dalvikvm(10350): Jit: resizing JitTable from
>   4096 to 8192 02-11 11:48:34.834: W/AmazonMobileAds AdLoader(10350):
>   Server Message: DISABLED_APP. Try again in 30 seconds; code: 400 02-11
>   11:48:34.834: D/AmazonMobileAds AdController(10350): adFailed 02-11
>   11:48:34.834: W/MainActivity(10350): Ad failed to load. Code: NO_FILL,
>   Message: Server Message: DISABLED_APP. Try again in 30 seconds

A few info that may be relevant:

1. The SDK is the most recent one (downloaded from https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-ads)
2. Most of the code are the same as example project (FloatingAdActivity.java)
3. If I change app key to the same as example project ("sample-app-v1_pub-2") it works
4. The app is registered but not yet published
5. I am not based in US

What should I change to make my app able to display Amazon Ads?

Comment: When you set the registration key, do you also set the test flag? AdRegistration.enableTesting(true);  Please let me know if this makes a difference.

Comment: Yes I have set the test flag, so that's not the reason...

Comment: Have you added your tax and payment information into the developer portal? You can get the DISABLED_APP message until Amazon has ingested this information.

Comment: @MikeHines Thanks for the comment. Do you mean the Tax Identity setting? I'd updated it on Feb 6, and Notification Center has confirmed that "Your tax identity information has been successfully validated.", not sure if there's anything else that I need to do.

Comment: @MikeHines Thanks for mentioning. I took the interview and after confirmation mail from amazon now ads are showing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turned out the problem is on Amazon's end, contacted them and got it fixed a day later.

The process was quite straight-forward: I used their developer contact portal: https://developer.amazon.com/help/contact-us.html, selected "*Mobile ads General*" as the *Subject*, and the content of my original question above as the *Message*. They were then able to determine the issue and fixed it.

Comment: You should include about the re-solution you did. It could help others in future.

Comment: @PareshMayani you were right, added more detail, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem too, with a similar error log.
After waiting for 30-60 minutes it went away by itself. (I didn't contact Amazon support and didn't change anything in my code).

It looks like adUnits need to "warm up" until ads are delivered for the first time.